# Connection ID required

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr, asp.net-core-2.0

I am trying to build a simple chat application using [SignalR](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR) with ASP.NET Core 2.0. 
The problem is that when I want to access one of my hub's url (`localhost:5000/chat`) I receive as a response: `Connection ID required` with error code `400`. I am using auto generated from template authentication (users are stored in local db).

Here are the following components:

[Startup.cs](https://pastebin.com/mNT6gfgd)

[ChatHub.cs](https://pastebin.com/0i7K2zS1)

Any help will be really appreciated. If you need any further information - please let me know.

Comment: can you also show the client code?

Comment: You can have it [here](https://pastebin.com/6RnLTvwf). But the view is not even rendered, so this code will not be executed as well.

Comment: Maybe you start at one point. Why is the view not rendered? Are you not finished? When do you get this error? Do you try somthing to send from server to the client? Error looks like no connection is established

Comment: I believe that is from the hub configuration in `Startup.cs` - because if I do not register the hub with:
 `app.UseSignalR(routes => {  routes.MapHub<ChatHub>("chat"); });` the page will be rendered.

I think my request is handled by SignalR middleware which notifies me for this error.

Comment: Make routes.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chat");

Comment: It throws error: `The route template cannot start with a '/' or '~' character. Parameter name: routeTemplate`.

Comment: app.UseSignalR(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapHub<Chat>("/chat");
            });
Is from the official the offical sample. There must be another bug

Comment: I believe it is connected to either user authentication or/and some configuration missing because I created the application (chat was working) on a server with no authentication.

Comment: :-) Maybe you should write this the question.

Comment: Adding the `/` came in a later version of the SignalR API. He may have been using a preview version.

Comment: `Connection ID is required` is correct behavior, isn't it? I mean the client is supposed to send its ID to the server

Comment: I have different controller and hub name and I am receiving the same message `Connection ID is required`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem was that I have **configured** the **hub** at route `/chat` while my **ChatController** was also responsible for it. After mapping the hub to **different route** than the controller's one everything went fine.

I changed this:
`app.UseSignalR(routes => { routes.MapHub<ChatHub>("chat"); });`

To this:
`app.UseSignalR(routes => { routes.MapHub<ChatHub>("chatter"); });`

Comment: THANK YOU! I was struggling with the same thing for few hours already. Didn't think naming and routing would be the reason...

Comment: This helped! Thanks for pointing this out. I for some reason deleted my default mvc routes, this post made me realize that and so I added them back in and boom. Worky worky! :)